# Does Cisco VPN client 5 support split tunneling and if so, how do I use it?

Tags: cisco-vpn, split-tunnel

We're using an old version of this VPN client (stipulated by a client) to connect to their system. It looks like this:
[image]

I am running this on a VM accessed by RDP and the issue is as soon as I connect, my RDP session is lost and the VM cannot be seen on the local network.

I *think* this is a case for "split tunneling" but I know next to nothing about this. The only settings VPN client gives me are these, and I would appreciate knowing what they mean:

[image]

I *only* want/need this VPN connection to be used to let me RDP into their machines. So is it possible? And if so is it something I control, or something they control at sysadmin level?

Comment: That depends on the Cisco firewall configuration. The network administrator configuring the firewall determines if split tunneling is allowed because it is a security risk to the network behind the firewall.

Comment: Thanks @RonMaupin. Could you expand why it is a security risk to allow the remote client (me) to continue to access my local network? Some risk of 'bridging' networks?

Comment: People do things like set up a connection from home, go into the office, then go back through the home PC to access the Internet, bypassing the business network security and policies. Also, if the home PC is compromised and controlled from the Internet, breaking the Internet connection when connected to the business is safer. It is up to the network administrator to allow split tunneling or not, and the default is not because it is safer.

Comment: Remember the time Target was hacked, costing it tens of millions of dollars? That was due to a vendor with access to the Target network getting hacked, and the perpetrator went through the vendor's network to the Target network. Split tunneling allows that type of thing, while disabling split tunneling is an impediment to that.